# Jboss-4.2.1.GA Deployment FAILED (.war file)

Tags: java, jboss

I am developing application in Ubuntu OS and I am using jboss-4.2.1.GA for deploying .war file. Now I want to test my application in IE10. So, I am deploying the same .war file in jboss server which is in Windows 7. Now, I can able to run my application in windows7 and I can see the login page, but I am not able to login. I don't know exactly what is the issue. Can any one please help me.

```
        2015-03-09 22:42:06,021 ERROR [org.jboss.deployment.scanner.URLDeploymentScanner] Incomplete Deployment listing:

--- Incompletely deployed packages ---
org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentInfo@262e21ee { url=file:/D:/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/all/deploy/mysql-ds.xml }
  deployer: org.jboss.deployment.XSLSubDeployer@5c419e74
  status: Deployment FAILED reason: Trying to install an already registered mbean: jboss.jca:service=LocalTxCM,name=DefaultDS
  state: FAILED
  watch: file:/D:/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/all/deploy/mysql-ds.xml
  altDD: null
  lastDeployed: 1425921117619
  lastModified: 1425921117596
  mbeans:

org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentInfo@22d2d2f7 { url=file:/D:/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/all/deploy/TagnosysEAR.ear }
  deployer: org.jboss.deployment.EARDeployer@520e7d53
  status: Deployment FAILED reason: URL file:/D:/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/all/tmp/deploy/tmp1757552006510094191TagnosysEAR.ear-contents/TagnosysWEB-exp.war/ deployment failed
  state: FAILED
  watch: file:/D:/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/all/deploy/TagnosysEAR.ear
  altDD: null
  lastDeployed: 1425921120795
  lastModified: 1425921118110
  mbeans:

--- MBeans waiting for other MBeans ---
ObjectName: tagnosys.com:service=AlarmCache
  State: CONFIGURED
  I Depend On:
    jboss:service=Naming
    tagnosys.com:service=Workflow
    jboss.har:service=Hibernate

ObjectName: tagnosys.com:service=Collector
  State: CONFIGURED
  I Depend On:
    jboss:service=Naming
    tagnosys.com:service=TagLocationCache
    tagnosys.com:service=Workflow
    jboss.har:service=Hibernate

ObjectName: tagnosys.com:service=Listener
  State: CONFIGURED
  I Depend On:
    jboss:service=Naming
    jboss.har:service=Hibernate
  Depends On Me:
    jboss.jmx:type=adaptor,name=ListenerProxy,protocol=jrmp,service=proxyFactory

ObjectName: jboss.jmx:type=adaptor,name=ListenerProxy,protocol=jrmp,service=proxyFactory
  State: CONFIGURED
  I Depend On:
    jboss:service=invoker,type=jrmp
    tagnosys.com:service=Listener

ObjectName: tagnosys.com:service=PatientFlow
  State: CONFIGURED
  I Depend On:
    jboss:service=Naming
    tagnosys.com:service=TagLocationCache
    tagnosys.com:service=Workflow
    jboss.har:service=Hibernate

ObjectName: tagnosys.com:service=Resource
  State: CONFIGURED
  I Depend On:
    jboss:service=Naming
    tagnosys.com:service=TagLocationCache
    tagnosys.com:service=Workflow
    jboss.har:service=Hibernate

ObjectName: tagnosys.com:service=RoomStatus
  State: CONFIGURED
  I Depend On:
    jboss:service=Naming
    tagnosys.com:service=TagLocationCache
    tagnosys.com:service=Workflow
    jboss.har:service=Hibernate

ObjectName: tagnosys.com:service=TagLocationCache
  State: CONFIGURED
  I Depend On:
    jboss:service=Naming
    jboss.har:service=Hibernate
  Depends On Me:
    tagnosys.com:service=Collector
    agnos.com:service=PatientFlow
    agnos.com:service=Resource
    agnos.com:service=RoomStatus
    jboss.jmx:type=adaptor,name=TagLocationCacheProxy,protocol=jrmp,service=proxyFactory
    agnos.com:service=Workflow

ObjectName: jboss.jmx:type=adaptor,name=TagLocationCacheProxy,protocol=jrmp,service=proxyFactory
  State: CONFIGURED
  I Depend On:
    jboss:service=invoker,type=jrmp
    agnos.com:service=TagLocationCache

ObjectName: agnos.com:service=Workflow
  State: CONFIGURED
  I Depend On:
    jboss:service=Naming
    agnos.com:service=TagLocationCache
    jboss.har:service=Hibernate
  Depends On Me:
    agnos.com:service=AlarmCache
    agnos.com:service=Collector
    agnos.com:service=PatientFlow
    agnos.com:service=Resource
    agnos.com:service=RoomStatus

ObjectName: jboss.har:service=Hibernate
  State: CONFIGURED
  I Depend On:
    jboss.jca:service=RARDeployer
    jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=MySqlDS
  Depends On Me:
    agnos.com:service=AlarmCache
    agnos.com:service=Collector
    agnos.com:service=Listener
    agnos.com:service=PatientFlow
    agnos.com:service=Resource
    agnos.com:service=RoomStatus
    agnos.com:service=TagLocationCache
    agnos.com:service=Workflow

ObjectName: jboss.web.deployment:war=AgnosysWEB.war,id=-621484854
  State: FAILED
  Reason: org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: URL file:/D:/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/all/tmp/deploy/tmp1757552006510094191AgnosysEAR.ear-contents/AgnosysWEB-exp.war/ deployment failed

--- MBEANS THAT ARE THE ROOT CAUSE OF THE PROBLEM ---
ObjectName: jboss.web.deployment:war=AgnosysWEB.war,id=-621484854
  State: FAILED
  Reason: org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: URL file:/D:/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/all/tmp/deploy/tmp1757552006510094191AgnosysEAR.ear-contents/AgnosysWEB-exp.war/ deployment failed

ObjectName: jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=MySqlDS
  State: NOTYETINSTALLED
  Depends On Me:
    jboss.har:service=Hibernate
```

**MySQl DS.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- $Id: mysql-ds.xml 63175 2007-05-21 16:26:06Z rrajesh $ -->
<!--  Datasource config for MySQL using 3.0.9 available from:
http://www.mysql.com/downloads/api-jdbc-stable.html
-->

<datasources>

  <local-tx-datasource>
    <jndi-name>MySqlDS</jndi-name>
    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tagnos</connection-url>
    <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
    <user-name>root</user-name>
    <password>root</password>
    <exception-sorter-class-name>org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.MySQLExceptionSorter</exception-sorter-class-name>
    <!-- should only be used on drivers after 3.22.1 with "ping" support
    <valid-connection-checker-class-name>org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.MySQLValidConnectionChecker</valid-connection-checker-class-name>
    -->
    <!-- sql to call when connection is created
    <new-connection-sql>some arbitrary sql</new-connection-sql>
      -->
    <!-- sql to call on an existing pooled connection when it is obtained from pool - MySQLValidConnectionChecker is preferred for newer drivers
    <check-valid-connection-sql>some arbitrary sql</check-valid-connection-sql>
      -->

    <!-- corresponding type-mapping in the standardjbosscmp-jdbc.xml -->
    <metadata>
       <type-mapping>mySQL</type-mapping>
    </metadata>
  </local-tx-datasource>

</datasources>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Seems like you didn't specify the Database connection MySqlDS on you Jboss. Check in your ubuntu for a name with MySqlDS inside and copy it to your Windows7 box.

Comment: @alphamikevictor thanks for reply. I copied that file. Still it is not working.

Comment: do you have the same error when deploying? On your server log do you see any other instance of MySqlDS? If the datasource is not up && running your application refuses to start

Comment: Edited question with new log.

Comment: Could you post the contents of file **D:/jboss-4.2.1.GA/server/all/deploy/mysql-ds.xml** (asterisking user/password if you prefer)